# AS3 event across multiple files

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm migrating from AS2 to AS3 and have this problem..

In my project I used main document file, which could load multiple nested animations as a separate files. In the main document I had a global function, for example:

```
_global.onAnimationEnd(mc:MovieClip){...}
```

and in animations (could be nested) I just called it like:

```
onAnimationEnd(this);
```

I'm new with AS3 but somehow thing that the proper way in AS3 is to use Event system, but I have problems to do it. Is there someone who can help with such an easy(AS2) issue?

Comment: migrating from as2 to as3 can be slightly annoying at first, things may appear complicated for no appearance reason. You should be able to get this running with an event that bubbles to the top level, and listen for it there. Have a quick look event bubbling in as3 here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e4f.html

Comment: also, if you have an as2 swf loaded in an as3 file, it might be worth having a look at SWF Bridge (http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html)

Answer (score 0):

The way that AS3 handles events is quite different to the AS2 approach. In AS3 events bubble up the object hierarchy and then back down to the originating object. If you have objects further up the hierarchy that are required to respond to an event it is necessary to set up event listeners on the recipient objects to handle the event as it bubbles.

Colin Moock's book Essential ActionScript 3.0 published by O'Reilly deals with it comprehensively. Not much help if you need a quick fix right now though…

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm using this approach:

- I'm using custom event like:

```
    package com.oldes {
        import flash.events.Event;
        public class GameEvent extends Event {
             public var data:Object;
             public static var ANIMATION_END = "onAnimationEnd";
             public function GameEvent(
                 type:String,
                 data: Object,
                 bubbles:Boolean=true,
                 cancelable:Boolean=false
            ){
                 super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
                 this.data = data;
            }
            override public function clone():Event {
                return new GameEvent (type, data, bubbles, cancelable);
            }
        }
    }
```

- In my deep nested animations I replaced:

```
onAnimationEnd(this);
```

with:

```
import com.oldes.GameEvent;
dispatchEvent(new GameEvent(GameEvent.ANIMATION_END,{anim: this}));
```

- Using clasic listeners to deal with the cached event.

EDIT: the external file with animations must be properly loaded into the correct context, but that's another AS3 story.